# Magento 2: How can I modify the product edit page depending on my custom product types

Tags: magento2, product, adminform

Is it posible to hide/remove default fields and fieldsets from the product edit page for custom product types? For example weight, price, tax_class...

Comment: you can change the via attribute set
Stores > Attributes > Attribute set (Default)

Comment: I know, but I also want to remove system fields like tax_class, weight...
I dont need these fields, I only need custum attributes.